# What factors govern the variable age of onset in Huntington's Disease?

Tags: genetics, pathology, human-genetics, neurodegenerative-disorders

"[Huntington's disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntington%27s_disease) (HD) is a neurodegenerative genetic disorder that affects muscle coordination and leads to cognitive decline and psychiatric problems." As we all know, this genetic disease exhibits a generally late age of onset. It has been shown that a increase in the number of CAG repeats in the hungtingtin gene is negatively correlated to the age of onset of the disease. However, patients having a  particular number of CAG repeats still have an **extremely variable** age of onset, which leads to believe that *other factors* are contributing to the Huntington phenotype.([reference](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v4/n4/abs/ng0893-398.html))

[image] ([reference](http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v4/n4/abs/ng0893-398.html))

**What other genetic or environmental factors have been shown to vary the age of onset of Huntington's disease?**

---

### References

**Andrew, S. E. et al.** *The relationship between trinucleotide (CAG) repeat length and clinical features of Huntington’s disease.* Nature Genetics 4, 398–403 (1993).

Answer (score 4):

There is quite a bit of data available from Venezuelan HD families, but they haven't identified the factors themselves. From the abstract of the [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14993615), emphasis mine:

> Analysis of the 83 kindreds that comprise the Venezuelan HD kindreds
>   demonstrates that residual variability in age of onset has **both
>   genetic and environmental components**. We created a residual age of
>   onset phenotype from a regression analysis of the log of age of onset
>   on repeat length. Familial correlations (correlation +/- SE) were
>   estimated for sibling (0.40 +/- 0.09), parent-offspring (0.10 +/-
>   0.11), avuncular (0.07 +/- 0.11), and cousin (0.15 +/- 0.10) pairs, **suggesting a familial origin for the residual variance in onset***. By
>   using a variance-components approach with all available familial
>   relationships, the additive genetic heritability of this residual age
>   of onset trait is 38%. A model, including shared sibling environmental
>   effects, estimated the components of additive genetic (0.37), shared
>   environment (0.22), and nonshared environment (0.41) variances,
>   ***confirming that approximately 40% of the variance remaining in onset
>   age is attributable to genes other than the HD gene and 60% is
>   environmental***.

*[This paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11449389) also suggests the same, with a smaller (but different) samples.

A recent study of an Italian sample suggests that [a polymorphism in Atg7](http://jnnp.bmj.com/content/83/Suppl_1/A20.3.short) (autophagy-related gene) is a modifier of age-of-onset, but this result does not generalize to a European cohort.

---

What is apparently *not* linked to age of onset in HD? [β-defensin copy number variation](http://iospress.metapress.com/content/p2271460602l7333/).

Also, [CTCF doesn't appear to be linked to the CAG repeat instability](http://jnnp.bmj.com/content/83/Suppl_1/A10.2.short) (mutations in CTCF have previously implicated in triplet repeat instability).

Mutations in PGC-1α, mitochondrial regulator, were previously associated with age of onset, but a more recent study suggests that [this might have been due to stratification of the sample](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00439-012-1205-z).

Similarly, a polymorphism in HAP-1 was previously associated with age of onset, but a [subsequent study found no evidence of association](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1353802012002088).

---

Altogether, these results suggest that population stratification needs to be taken into account when evaluating associations between age of onset and genetic polymorphisms.  It is also possible that there are population-specific genetic factors that affect age of onset.