# Can Huntington's Disease be homozygous dominant?

Tags: genetics, neurodegenerative-disorders

Can Huntington's Disease be homozygous dominant? I am not sure whether the individual who is homozygous dominant for Huntington's Disease will survive into adulthood, or die when they are infants or fetuses. I cannot find any good information on that topic.

Comment: It's a one gene defect AFAIK.

Comment: We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). In particular, a quick look at the "Related" links automatically generated next to your post will show you that many Huntington's patients reach adulthood before they show symptoms. For example: [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7967/). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site . Thanks! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's relatively rare. 
The disease progresses more rapidly in homozygotes than in heterozygotes.<sup>1</sup>

### Reference

1: [Ferdinando Squitieri, Cinzia Gellera, Milena Cannella, Caterina Mariotti, Giuliana Cislaghi, David C. Rubinsztein, Elisabeth W. Almqvist, David Turner, Anne‐Catherine Bachoud‐Lévi, Sheila A. Simpson, Martin Delatycki, Vittorio Maglione, Michael R. Hayden, Stefano Di Donato, Homozygosity for CAG mutation in Huntington disease is associated with a more severe clinical course, Brain, Volume 126, Issue 4, April 2003, Pages 946–955, https://doi.org/10.1093/brain/awg077](https://academic.oup.com/brain/article/126/4/946/331910#4567935)

Sourse: Homozygosity for CAG mutation in Huntington disease is associated with a more severe clinical course; Ferdinando Squitieri et.al. Brain, Volume 126, Issue 4, April 2003, Pages 946–955, https://doi.org/10.1093/brain/awg077

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Good job on providing a supporting reference, but in the future please include the complete reference information since links can break. Also, do you have a reference to support the rarity of homozygotes and what that means? Are they less common that would expected for the prevalence of heterozygotes in the population? Underrepresented in the children of two heterozygotes? Thanks! 